# Search a way to make VSCode compliant with a ESling Rule

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

i use VsCode and i can't find a way to handle this Eslint rule :

```
"object-curly-spacing": [
            2,
            "never",
            {
                "objectsInObjects": true
            }
        ],
```

Somebody have a solution?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use that rule?  If so, you will need to install the ESLint extension.

Comment: Yes and i already have this extension. What I want is to configure vscode, so that it format correctly the code on save.

Comment: Do you have that rule in a eslintrc.json file in your root folder?  And then  "editor.formatOnSave": true in your user settings?,

Comment: Yeah. My code is format on save but it does not take into account this rule. I tried to fix this in user preference but I found nothing to handle this case

Comment: But that rule is in your eslintrc.json file?

Comment: Yes. It is. I have no choice. I must use it.

Comment: Where did you get the "2" argument, I don't see it in the specs https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-spacing More like object-curly-spacing: ["error", "never", { "objectsInObjects": true }]

Comment: The 2 means activate this rule and raised an error if it is not respect.

Comment: I guess the only other option to watch out for is eslint.autoFixOnSave - enables auto fix on save. Please note auto fix on save is only available if VS Code's files.autoSave is either off, onFocusChange or onWindowChange.